# Why does boost::when_all spawn a new thread

Tags: c++, boost, future, boost-thread

I have the following code, compiled with Boost 1.62.

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/executors/loop_executor.hpp>

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
int main() {

    auto start = boost::make_ready_future<int>();

    boost::loop_executor ex;

    auto a = start.then(ex, [](auto &&) { std::cout << "A"; }).share();

    auto b = boost::when_all(a).then(ex, [](auto &&) { std::cout << "B";} );
    auto c = boost::when_all(a).then(ex, [](auto &&) { std::cout << "C";} );

    auto d = boost::when_all(std::move(b),std::move(c)).then(ex, [](auto &&) { std::cout << "D";} );

    while ( ex.try_executing_one() )
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

    d.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This spawns 4 tasks (A,B,C,D) with a diamond dependency over them ( B and C depend on A, D depends on B and C ).

Given the fact that I am using a `loop_executor`, I expected this code to not spawn any thread and output either "ABCD" or "ACBD".

Instead this code might or might not deadlock at `d.get()` (just reduce the sleep time to zero to see it deadlocking), because every call to `when_all` spawns a new thread that is used to wait on the `futures`.

I was under the impression that `when_all` could simply be implemented in terms of `.then`, some buffer to store the task result and an atomic counter.

**Question:**

Is there a fundamental design reason that requires `when_all` to spawn a new thread?

In particular I am wondering if this behavior is to be expected also from an hypothetical implementation of the concurrency TS.

Comment: You should probably ask that on the boost mailing list. From my POV it doesn't look like it's necessary to spawn a Thread. `when_all` could allocate  some shared state, attach continuations to all futures and in these check whether all have finished. The only reason I could think of when you want a Thread is if you want to guarantee that the overall continuation never runs synchronously from one of the inner continuations. But as this can be controlled through the executor it's not a  good reason.